# Transparent div background, with a tint of color?

Tags: css, html, colors, transparency

Can anyone tell me how to make a div's background transparent, but with a tint of color, such as black. I've tried this using CSS although I can only get the div to be either transparent or filled with color.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks all for the answers.
I've got it sorted now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's `opacity` as per Pekka's answer, but it will make the content of the div transparent as well as the background. If that's not what you want, you could:

1. have two divs, one with the opacity/alpha acting as a background, and another solid one for the content positioned on top of it. However the positioning can be tricky for variable-size elements. Or,
2. use a semi-opaque background, either by using an [`rgba()` colour](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) (in browsers other than IE), or a PNG background image with an alpha channel (which works in IE7-8 but needs an `AlphaImageLoader` fix for IE6, which also means you have to make the image as large as you could possibly need it, as AlphaImageLoader won't tile).

Answer (score 6):

There is one more option ( although not supported in all browsers ). Use rgba():

```
/* apply a shade of seafoam green (50% transparent) to "tinted" class */
.tinted {    
    background-color: rgba(129,254,188,0.5);
}
```

Here's a nice [easy to read article](http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/not_so_clear_css_opacity_and_rgba) on a few methods.

Things are a whole lot easier if you don't care about IE6.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `opacity` (and its IE sibling `alpha`) for that.

[Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) has a good list of how to achieve that consistently in most browsers.

Comment: Not a great solution if you want *only* a background tinted, but it will work.

Comment: @Atomiton true. I sort of overread that part - to tint a background in a dynamically sized element, the PNG is definitely the way to go, taking into consideration @bobince's comments. It's still too early for `rgba`, as no IE supports it - otherwise, it would be the most elegant way hands down.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a PNG semi transparent image. Often the easiest way out, cause when playing with `opacity` you also change the opacity of the text.

Comment: Good point. Only thing to notice, semi-transparent PNGs need a workaround in IE6 to work. And a word of warning, never combine semi-transparent PNGs with `opacity`, it acts up in all IE browsers including 8. Use either one method or the other but never the both combined in one element.

Comment: Make sure you use a program like PNGOutWin (http://www.ardfry.com/pngoutwin/) to compress the image before using it so you don't chew up all your bandwidth though.

Comment: Why bother when you could use a _real css_ semi-transparent background?

Comment: This is almost 4 years old, that's why

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp has some examples

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery plugin that will handle everything for you, Transify http://jorenrapini.com/blog/css/transify-a-jquery-plugin-to-easily-apply-transparency-opacity-to-an-elements-background

I was running into this problem every now and then, so I decided to write something that would make life a lot easier. The script is less than 2kb and it only requires 1 line of code to get it to work, and it will also handle animating the opacity of the background if you like.